# slider images in Revolution Slider 6.2.23 not working well for all device

Tags: wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

i have installed slider revolution and added many slide under that but all images are not showing when in mobile device
am using Revolution Slider 6.2.23 and am unable to find setting for that

Answer (score 0):

Check the console for errors first. Also, try to switch to Twenty Twenty theme and disable all plugins except the revolution slider. If everything is Ok the problem is in your theme or there is a plugin conflict.